# How do I delete every row besides row 1 in google spreadsheets using google scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to wipe every row besides row 1 but I don't know how

Answer (score 2):

#### All rows in all sheets of Spreadsheet except row 1

```
function delrow2plusallsheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    let mr = sh.getMaxRows();
    sh.deleteRows(2,mr - 1)
  });
}
```

Comment: Congrats on 50k!! 

Comment: Thanks.   Good to see you around more lately